# spring request body assign name to array / list

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am currently accepting the student list in Request Body.

```
public void saveStudents(@RequestBody List<Student> Students){

}
```

which is accepting below JSON

```
 [
      {
        "name": "",
        "rollNo": ""
      },
      {
        "name": "",
        "rollNo": ""
      }
  ]
```

Instead of the above, I want to accept

```
{
  "students": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "rollNo": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "",
      "rollNo": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried

```
 public void saveStudents(@RequestBody @JsonProperty("students") List<Student> Students){

 }
```

But it is not accepting.

**I do not want to create another object which contains the student list.**

Is there any way to assign name to array/list?

Comment: "I do not want to create another object which contains the student list." => Why? This would be an easy way to go (and the correct one).

Comment: API which I am using is exposed to users which they use for bulk upload

I am using Spring validations before accepting the list

Actual API is accepting complex object and list size can be up to 1000. To make users life easier, want to show which object has error.
When I use List<Student> it gives the object which has error in the exception. 
But when I create object lets say ListofStudent which has List<Student> I get the error message about the field which has an error but not the exact object in which that field is present.
so I want to avoid using another object which has list.

Comment: How about using a web filter to extract the part of request body which your controller consumes and pass to it?

Comment: @LHCHIN yes thought about it. and it will work.
 If there is any Jackson annotation to represent array/list name It will be really great as it will avoid the complexity

Answer (score 2):

`@RequestBody` annotation stands for sent content - means JSON. There exists no additional mapping methods for scrambling those content inside the annotion, so body represents always an object which can be mapped.

jackson annotation `@JsonProperty` is defined to annotate fields/methods inside your JSON class - so has no effect at your controller method/parameters

### Suggested way

You should IMHO simply accept that you need to create a new class, because it is the easiest and also the correct way to do: For example

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StudentList {

    // simplest example approach by public field...
    public List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And your controller code should look like:

```
    @RequestMapping(path="/api/students",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void saveStudents(@RequestBody StudentList list) {
        // do stuff...
    }
```

So the JSON in body represents a clazz. It's easy to maintain, easy to read, extendable, KISS and also uses spring/jackson defaults without any special configuration.

### Other, not suggested ways

I thought about other options to handle this, but none is KISS or good maintainable:

#### Converter

You could write a converter class, see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest

But I think this is an overkill / over engineering to solve avoiding a new value class.

#### Parse JSON (extreme ugly)

You could handle JSON parsing directly

```
    @RequestMapping(path="/api/students",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void saveStudents(@RequestBody String json) {
          ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
          JsonNode node = Json.node(json);
          JsonNode students = node.get("students");
          // ... than convert back to a list containing students ...
    }
```

But this would be ... terrible to maintain, not KISS , not readable .

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
 saveStudents(@RequestParam(value="students") List<Student> students)
 saveStudents(@RequestBody Map<String,List<Student>> body)
```

Hope that could help you.

Comment: `@RequestParam` is used to map to query parameters, form data, and parts in multipart requests. Using a `Map` allows for more than one list of students bound to several keys, which then have to be manually analyzed. This is a bad suggestion!